# How to allow connections to different databases at the same time

Tags: plsqldeveloper

When I first started using plsql developer, it would allow each window to have a separate connection to a different database.

At the time I found that annoying, so I turned it off.

But now I need to compare objects across databases - ie : how is the view on dev4 different than the same view on dev5.

I can't find the setting / preference I changed.

Help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok the quick answer to this is Configure -> Preferences -> Connection ( under Oracle grouping) -> uncheck/check 'Allow Multiple Connections'.

With this checked, you have an option at the bottom of every SQL window to choose a separate connection to a database ( a downward facing triangle). You ALSO have the 'Connect as Main' option when you right click on a db connection, which will connect all subsequent SQL windows to that db.

With this unchecked, the 'Connect' option goes away - leaving you with only 'Connect as Main', and the option at the bottom of each SQL window goes away.

FYI